# Rails: How to do i18n on a dropdown menu in simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, simple-form, rails-i18n

I have a `simple_form` that has a dropdown menu with a collection of options. I wish to have the options saved as integers, but the text shown in the dropdown as a string based on the locale. As follows:

```
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
```

I currently have the options defined as class methods in `MyModel`, as follows:

```
def self.options
 [['Option 1', 1], ['Option 2', 2]]
end
```

Without i18n I had the following working:

`f.input :dropdown, collection: MyModel::boolean, include_blank: false`

Adding the locales, I tried

`f.input :dropdown, collection: t(MyModel::boolean, scope: 'simple_form'), include_blank: false`

But this raises an error:

> > translation missing: en.simple_form.Option 1.1

It looks as if it looks for both the array key and value in the translation.

Any suggestions how to make i18n work for the collection?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem.  Why not add a callback before_save in your model that converts these values "1" "2" etc. to integer?  Such as "1".to_i

Comment: The question here is how to make the i18n work in such case. Your call_back is a useful suggestions for saving the data. Any ideas on the i18n?

Comment: Hmm perhaps keeping the collection the same but only changing the view to the user would work better?  I'll post what I'm thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Since simpleform collections accept procs you can call a block on the label_method that will format your string as needed which may be what you're looking for:

```
f.input :dropdown, collection: MyModel::boolean, include_blank: false, :label_method => lambda { |item| t(item.last) }
```